# External protocol request

Tags: google-chrome, browser, download, frontend, icalendar

I am trying to build something that will return an .ics file and open it in Apple iCal. I have checked out websites that do something like this and noticed that in Chrome, a "External protocol request" dialog box comes up and then, if you click OK, iCal opens, whereas Safari just opens up iCal automatically. Firefox opens up a "launch application" dialog box which lets you choose which application to open it in; if you choose calendar then it opens. How do I get my application to evoke such behavior? Right now I can only make the file download, but it doesn't automatically open. Is this a frontend thing or backend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a simple `<a href="">` link, but instead of using `http://` to start the url, use `webcal://`