# Is it possible to open a Chrome External Protocol Request through a Chrome Extention Content Script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've always been confused on how to use an external protocol request.

My external request url is 'playUpun://launch:5122' and I am trying to call it from a Content Script that'll be running from the webpage and keep getting an error about

> jquery.js:4 XMLHttpRequest cannot load playUpun://launch:5122. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution via [External protocol request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17953768/external-protocol-request)

Had to use an `<a href="">` div flag.